# Wiring a stove top infinite switch

Tags: electrical, stove

I have an older model Frigidaire stove infinite switch is unplugged, the infinite switch has 4 prongs 3 on one side 2 on the other I need to know where the power negative and ground wires go and where the stove element negative and positive plugs in on the infinite switch.

I have searched everywhere and  I cannot find out where the wires go to an infinite switch I can just find out how to test it.

Comment: Both "Line" power wires are 120V from ground (and 240V from each other - AC, not DC) and the element is also getting AC power - so it's not negative, not ground (other than the case of the stove), and not positive.

Comment: there is no `positive` or `negative`

Answer (score 2):

If your switch has the labels still on it, specifically H1, H2, L1, L2 and P, then you can use this:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Source: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/operation-of-infinite-switch

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotal input that is not theoretically supported:  I have replaced several of these switches.  In one instance, I swapped the L1/L2 red/black wires on one of the switches.  That switch/element worked OK until the other burner on the same side (daisy-chained to the replaced control) was turned on.  BOOM!  Arcs, sparks, and smoke on the second burner.  I replaced that exploded control.  New controller/burner worked fine.  Turned on second burner (a different burner from the first time but same side).  BOOM!  The un-replaced switch blew up!!

I have no idea why swapping red/black between L1/L2 would cause this, but it happened twice.

Point of this:  I have seen wiring diagrams that specify L1/L2 be connected to 'input' wires.  Apparently, it is necessary to ensure that ALL L1s are connected to the same side of the phase..say, all of them 'red' wire.  Sure, 'red goes where red came from' is a good idea.  I've repaired many an electrical device, have never run into this issue.

Then again, I have probably never reversed red/black before, either.

Comment: Your BOOMS are very much "theoretically supported": just look at the schematic in the earlier answer. All the L1 inputs, from all the infinite switches, will be connected to one side of the pilot lamp when they are turned on, and so will all be connected to each other. If two of the switches are both on, but have reversed L1 and L2 connections to the feed wires, then there will be a bolted 240V short at the point all those pilot lamp wires are connected together.